# Jboss deploying a ear and war file in the same server instance

Tags: spring, deployment, jboss, war, ear

Is it possible in Jboss deploying a ear and war file in the same server instance? If so any good source to get started? Any suggestion.

I have two applications deployed under my default deploy folder of jboss. I am running one application from which i have to call the other application to get some data. Is this possible? If so how to get started??

Answer (score 0):

It is actually recommended that you only put 1 application in a server instance as a time.  That said, I have had multiple ears and wars running in the same instance while I am developing.  But for production it is better to separate them out.  Since there is no extra cost involved this makes it easier to observe and debug apps.

Do you have a specific reason for wanting them to run side by side?

What version of JBoss are you running.